# How do I pack a function from a static library into an .so file with fortran (MKL)

Tags: linux, fortran, shared-libraries, intel-mkl

I'm trying to speed up an optimization routine using MKL's blas implementation in fortran. I need to have the result in a shared library so that it is accessible from a larger script. I can compile and link my code without any warnings, but the resulting `.so` file has an undefined reference to the blas routine I'm trying to call, namely `dgemm`.

relevant section of the fortran code:

```
subroutine sumsquares(params, Mx, flen, glen, numr, numcols, g, lambda, res)
 implicit none
 integer, intent(in):: flen, glen, numr, numcols
 real(8), dimension(flen, numcols) :: params
 real(8), dimension(flen, numcols) :: g
 real(8), dimension(flen, numcols) :: gc
 real(8), dimension(flen, glen) :: Mx 

 gc = -g
 call dgemm('N', 'N', flen, glen, numcols, 1, Mx, flen, params, numcols, 1, gc,flen)
 return
end subroutine sumsquares
```

and the corresponding makefile

```
FC=ifort
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/lib/intel64
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/lib/intel64
INCLUDE=/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/include
FPATH=/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/include
CPATH=/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/include
FFLAGS=-i8 -I$(MKLROOT)/include/intel64/ilp64 -I$(MKLROOT)/include
LDFLAGS= -shared -nofor-main -fPIC
LINKLIBS=-fPIC -shared -L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_blas95_ilp64.a -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm

sumsquares: sumsquares.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -fPIC /opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/include/blas.f90 -o blas95.o
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -nofor-main -c -fPIC sumsquares.f90
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) sumsquares.o $(LINKLIBS) sumsquares.o
```

As I said, I can run `make` without any warnings, but when I run `nm sumsquares.so | grep dgemm` I see `U dgemm_`, and when I try to load the `.so` file, I crash with a segfault (while calling an unrelated subroutine, so I don't think it's related to this code). How do I get the linker to put in the relevant function into the `so` file?

**Update**

I am loading the `so` file in an R script by calling `dyn.load` in R as follows:

Variation 1:

```
dyn.load("/home/me/path/sumsquares.so")
```

Variation 2:

```
dyn.load("/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.1.107/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so")
dyn.load("/home/me/path/sumsquares.so")
```

Both variations lead to the same result, with a segfault.

**Update # 2**

I should point out that intel MKL static libaries *are* compiled with the `-fPIC` flag, at least [according to the documentation](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-linux-developer-guide/top/linking-your-application-with-the-intel-math-kernel-library/building-custom-shared-objects.html). I clearly don't know what I'm doing, but from what I can tell, something like this should be possible.

As `blas` is used extensively in scientific computing, I am concerned about collisions with different versions. If I'm linking statically within my `so` file, and load that `so` file into a program that uses a different `blas` implementation, would that lead to a collision, or would my library play nice?

Comment: But why are you kinking the ILP64 version? Did you go through the online linking selection for MKL? ILP64 is not likely compatible with your code, because your are compiling it as usual LP64. A segfault is a different problem. You managed to link a library correctly, according to our answers. But you are just linking the wrong one - most likely.

Comment: You must use https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.html

Comment: @VladimirF You're right about the segfault being related to me using ILP64 instead of LP64. That was an additional problem I was unaware of at the time (the program would still fail when it tried to call dgemm, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the library is really static, you cannot put in a shared library. Shared object code is compiled in a different way, so that it can work independent of the position. Flags like `-fPIC` must be used that are not used for static libraries.

Either compile your BLAS with `dgemm` as a dynamic library and load it before you load your custom library (perhaps the R `dyn.load` will load the dependencies automatically, I do not know, you can try) or just include the code of DGEMM into your own library and compile everything together into one .so.

Do not forget you have to use the MKL Linking Advisor https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.html Do NOT link with the ILP64 library, unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason to do so.

Also, although most of the MKL is shipped with static libraries built using `-fPIC`, the Fortran 95 interfaces to LAPACK and BLAS are not. The source files for the interfaces are included, so you need to compile them yourself with `-fPIC` if you want to use them. They are found at `$MKLROOT/interfaces/blas95` and `$MKLROOT/interfaces/lapack95`.

Comment: It's possible to link static library into shared library if it contains files that were compiled with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @yugr Sure, I hope I did not imply it is not anywhere. As I wrote, it is all about that flag.

Comment: Well, the "if the library is really static, you cannot put in a shared library" statement does imply it.

Comment: @yugr Depending how we understand "really static". Anyway, the subsequent sentences hopefully make it clear.

Comment: @VladimirF I'll try loading dgemm dynamically. I've updated the question with relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the linker to put in the relevant function into the so file?

That's not how shared libraries work; you need to ship the `so` with your other files (and set the appropriate `RPATH`), or link to a static version of the library.

When you say:

> when I try to load the .so file, I crash with a segfault

This sounds like you're trying to directly `dlopen()` or something similar; just let the dynamic (runtime) linker do its job.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've updated my answer with more information, but when I set the `RPATH` with `-Wl,-rpath=xxx`, nothing seems to change. Could you provide an example? I also thought I was linking to static libraries, but could be wrong.

Comment: I guess I'm not asking my question very well, because I'm trying to ask how to link to the static version of the library when building my shared library. I would be happy to for suggestions on how to make this more clear